Does registering a large number of styles with wp_register_style negatively impact site optimization?
If I register a significant number of styles using wp_register_style in functions.php, will it negatively impact site optimization?
I plan to register the styles in functions.php without actually enqueuing them at that time. Instead, I'll enqueue the styles with wp_enqueue_style when specific component parts are loaded or when a shortcode is triggered. Ideally, it might be best to register styles only when specific template pages are loaded. However, I want to register all the styles initially so that they can be enqueued whenever necessary, such as when applying styles to dynamically created DOM elements through component parts or shortcodes.

Have you tried this? It should be pretty easy to register the same style say 1000 times by adding a number on the end of the style handle in a for loop. Note that what you're trying to do will force those styles to be in the footer unless you. hold everything up with output buffers which will hurt time to first byte

wp_register_styles do not actually import the style in code. You can put it anywhere you want, without big impact on performance.
The moment when you actually import a style file registered via wp_register_styles is when you call wp_enqueue_styles.
wp_register_style( 'my-plugin', plugins_url( 'my-plugin/css/plugin.css' ) );

if ( true === $i_want_this_script_to_be_included ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'my-plugin' );
}

You can read more in docs: wp_register_style and wp_enqueue_style
wp_register_script and wp_enqueue_script works the same way for JS scripts.

That's what I wanted to know, thaks!
